# Getting Error Message in Eclipse: "error: no match for 'operator='"

Tags: c++, eclipse

I've a Problem with C++ in Eclipse and i'm a newby.
I get the following Error Message:

> ..\src\Aufgabe5.cpp:16:23: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Stammbaum' and 'Stammbaum*')

I think the problem is the initializition. But i don't how to fix this.
Main Class:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Stammbaum.h"
    using namespace std;

    int main() {

    Stammbaum baum = new Stammbaum();

    baum.createNode("Vorname", "Nachname");

    Node* anchor = baum.getAnchor();
    cout << "Vorname: " << anchor->vorname << " - Nachname: " << anchor->nachname << endl;

    }
```

Stammbaum.cpp:

```
#include "Stammbaum.h"

Node *anchor, *pointer;

Stammbaum::Stammbaum() {
    anchor = NULL;
    pointer = NULL;

}

Stammbaum::~Stammbaum() {

}

Node* navigiereNachOben(Node* tempPointer, Node* pointer){

    if(tempPointer == pointer->Mutter)
        return pointer;

    if(tempPointer == pointer->Vater)
        return pointer;

    navigiereNachOben(tempPointer, pointer->Mutter);
    navigiereNachOben(tempPointer, pointer->Vater);

    if(pointer->Mutter == NULL || pointer->Vater == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
}

void createNode(string vorname, string nachname){
    if(anchor == NULL){
        anchor = new Node;
        anchor->vorname = vorname;
        anchor->nachname = nachname;
        pointer = new Node;
        pointer = anchor;
    }
}

void nachUnten(int geschlecht){
    if(geschlecht == 0)
        pointer = pointer->Mutter;
    else
        pointer = pointer->Vater;
}
void nachOben(){

    Node* tempPointer = pointer;
    pointer = anchor;
    pointer = navigiereNachOben(tempPointer, pointer);

}

void addMother(Node* node){
    pointer->Mutter = node;
}

void addFather(Node* node){
    pointer->Vater = node;
}

Node* getAnchor(){
    return anchor;
}
```

Stammbaum.h:

```
#ifndef NULL
#define NULL   ((void *) 0)
#endif

#ifndef STAMMBAUM_H_
#define STAMMBAUM_H_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
        std::string vorname;
        std::string nachname;

        Node* Vater = NULL;
        Node* Mutter = NULL;
};

class Stammbaum {



public:
    Stammbaum();
    virtual ~Stammbaum();
    void nachOben(Node* pointer);
    void nachUnten(Node* pointer, int geschlecht);
    void addMother(Node* node);
    void addFather(Node* node);
    void createNode(string vorname, string nachname);
    Node* getAnchor();

private:

    Node* navigiereNachOben(Node* tempPointer, Node* pointer);

};

#endif /* STAMMBAUM_H_ */
```

I don't know how to fix this Problem :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
Stammbaum baum = new Stammbaum();
```

with

```
Stammbaum baum;
```

`baum` is just a regular variable. There is no need to use `new`.

Also (common beginner mistake), don't do this

```
Stammbaum baum();
```

because that makes `baum` a function prototype.

Comment: Now i'm getting a new error:
'''C:\Users\maxim\eclipse-workspace\Aufgabe5\Debug/../src/Aufgabe5.cpp:19: undefined reference to `Stammbaum::getAnchor()''''

Comment: Maybe you forgot to implement the `Stammbaum::getAnchor()` function. Edit: Looks like you did not implement it. Instead you implemented a free function of the same name `Node* getAnchor(){` hint: you forgot the `Stammbaum::` part in the definition.

Comment: Yes, like this `Node* Stammbaum::getAnchor(){ ... }`. Same with all the others in stammbaum.cpp.

Comment: Also you probably want to make these: `Node *anchor, *pointer;` class members instead of global variables. What if you had two `Stammbaum` objects?

Comment: That helps. :D
Thank you guys